# Adding version number from Jenkins to Apk?

Tags: android, ant, jenkins, hudson, adb

I have a jenkins server that uses ANT to build my android project , what I need to do is to add the jenkins build number into my apk. So that I can do : getprop my.version on ADB .
One idea I had was to write the jenkins build to a file and bundle that on the apk so that I can read this file and set the property on Accepting the INTENT . What I need to know is how to put a file in apk resources with ant? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with including the build number into the app version (with properly updating the AndroidManifest.xml) and then getting it from the package manager on the device when needed?

Comment: I think Jenkins will have to check out the source code in order to write to it, and It has to be read from getprop.

Comment: AFAIK, jenkins generates the build number whenever we fire a new build from it. So is there a way that we can put that generated build number back in to app so that it can be viewed in screens like About ?